# Undefined local variable or method friendship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add some social functionality to my app, and following [RailsCast #163 about self-referential association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?view=asciicast), but I have a problem with deleting friendship.

On `user#show` page I have 2 columns: with `@users` and `@friends`. The `show` method from `UsersController` is:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @users = User.all
  @friends = @user.friends
end
```

Also I'm using `<%= render @users %>` and `<%= render @friends %>` partials, both of them renders `_user.html.erb` from `users` folder, which is the following:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <%= gravatar_for user, size: 30 %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= user.name %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <% if current_user.friends.exists?(user) %>
        <%= link_to 'Remove friend', friendship, :method => :delete %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to 'Add friend', friendships_path(:friend_id => user), method: :post %>
    <% end %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Everything is ok with models and controllers, as I've checked everything a hundred times. But when I try to open a page I receive an error `undefined local variable or method friendship` from this line `<%= link_to 'Remove friend', friendship, :method => :delete %>`.

Comment: can you run rake routes?

Comment: Yes! On `rake routes` everything is ok too. `friendship DELETE /friendships/:id(.:format) friendships#destroy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks awful, but seems that `current_user.friendships.find_all_by_friend_id(user.id).first` instead of `friendship` solved my problem. But I'm sure that there is more simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Like the error says, `friendship` is not defined. You need to pass instead of `friendship`, the user you want to delete. For example:

```
<%= link_to 'Remove friend', user, :method => :delete %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to 'Remove friend', friendship_path(user), :method => :delete %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: According to your routes, you have to use `friendship_path(friendship_id)`. I don't know how to get you friendship_id...

Answer (score 0):

if you have an instance variable defined in your controller (@friendship or @user) use that opposed to user or friendship for the route.

```
<%= link_to 'Remove friend', @user, :method => :delete %>
```